# How can I separate value from different arrays?

Tags: php

I have first information table:

[image: first]

and second:

[image: second]

As 1st table can see #005 has TC20151200730; #008,#009 have TC20151200738.

I need to show id(#005,#008,#009) in 2nd table, but if there is more than one record, then ids will stick together(2nd pic left).

How can display as right side of 2nd pic?

```
 foreach($jobSumID as $job)
        {
            $jobList=explode(";",$job);

            if(in_array($row["ets_tcase_code"], $jobList))
            {
                if(base_num_rows($getActionSQL)>1)
                    $date .="#".$jobList[0]."<br/>";  //show id 008,009             

                else
                    $date .="#".$jobList[0]."<br/>";  //show id 005
            }
        }
```

I store the 1st pic data to a array, since the id is generate by loop:

```
 Array( [0] => 001;TC20151200694 
        [1] => 002;TC20151200723 
        [2] => 003;TC20151200723 
        [3] => 004;TC20151200723 
        [4] => 005;TC20151200730 
        [5] => 006;TC20151200723 
        [6] => 007;TC20151200716 
        [7] => 008;TC20151200738 
        [8] => 009;TC20151200738 
     )
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry about that, but i am not able to post image for current status.

Comment: @Ravi Hirani Thanks for edit.

Comment: are you looking something like join?

Comment: emm, nope, i need separate when record more than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping!
I make my data to multidimensional array:

```
Array ( [TC20151200694] => 001 
        [TC20151200723] => Array ( [0] => 002 [1] => 003 [2] => 004 [3] => 006 ) 
        [TC20151200730] => 005 
        [TC20151200716] => 007 
        [TC20151200738] => Array ( [0] => 008 [1] => 009 )
      )
```

And below is my code to display as right side of 2nd pic:

```
if(array_key_exists($row["ets_tcase_code"],$jobSumID))
{   
    $test="";
    $j=0;
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($jobSumID);$i++)
    {
        if(is_array($jobSumID[$row["ets_tcase_code"]]))
        {
            if($j<sizeof($jobSumID[$row["ets_tcase_code"]]))
                $date.="#".$jobSumID[$row["ets_tcase_code"]][0]."<br>";

            array_shift($jobSumID[$row["ets_tcase_code"]]);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $date.="#".$jobSumID[$row["ets_tcase_code"]]."<br>";
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is anything but clear. You also do not provide us the right data to work with. That being said, what you're looking for is something that splits each entry in your array on semicolon using `explode` and stores this data in another array, like below:

```
<?php

// Example data to work with
$array = array(
    '001;1',
    '002;1',
    '003;1',
    '004;2',
    '005;2',
    '006;2',
    '007;2',
);

$jobs = array();
foreach( $array as $job )
{
    $joblist = explode(';',$job);
    $number = $joblist[0];
    $id = $joblist[1];

    // Let's store the gathered data in the $jobs array
    $jobs[] = array(
        'number' => $number,
        'id' => $id,
    );
}

// An example to output the data
foreach( $jobs as $v )
{
    echo 'Job with number ' . $v['number'] . ' has id: ' . $v['id'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think there is a bit different from mine. My final result should the job number will only show 1 time, and the id will show separately as right side in 2nd pic.